# How to keep cursor position in a react input element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

The cursor keeps going to the end. How to keep the cursor position when editing from the the middle of the string?

[image]

Code that I am using is:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

class MyFancyForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {myValue: ""};
    }

    handleCommaSeparatedChange = event => {
        const {value} = event.target;
        this.setState({myValue: value});
    };




    render() {
        return(
            <form >

                <div>
                    <label>
                        Cursor position looser
                        <br />
                        <input onChange={this.handleCommaSeparatedChange} value={this.state.myValue} />
                    </label>
                </div>


            </form>
        )
    }
}

const element = <MyFancyForm />;

ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement);
```

Any idea how could I achieve it?

Comment: I tried your exact code and I don't get this jumpy cursor behavior. What browser is this?

Comment: @Chris are you sure? this is a known drawback of controlled inputs. Check this out: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYzZVj

Comment: @Josep Aaaah! D: i've been building these lately and i had no idea this happened until just now

Comment: @Josep I actually do not see the problem at https://codesandbox.io/s/km35znxvx5 although i see it at the jsfiddle you posted. Could it be a bundler/version issue ?

Comment: I'm getting crazy about how [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QYzZVj) it's wrong but [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/km35znxvx5) is ok.

Comment: @Vencovsky well it's not the browser, or the provided code, that means the only thing we are left with is versioning of the libraries. i think Gabriele Petrioli is on to something.

Comment: @redochka where were you running this code on? Your local environment or something like codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: @Chris my browser. Chrome: 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @redochka, I meant, where is your code hosted on? Are you building locally or are you using a site such as codepen.io, jsfiddle.net or similar?

Comment: I am building locally and serving my files using a local web server

Comment: @Vencovsky It looks like when using Babel we get the problem. When importing react directly there is no problem such in Gabriele Petrioli example.

Comment: @redochka, it might have been this bug? https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1683-february-21-2019

Answer (score 14):

just change `value` into `defaultValue` - it worked both in codepen and codesandbox for me

```
class MyFancyForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {myValue: ""};
    }

    handleCommaSeparatedChange = event => {
        const {value} = event.target;
        this.setState({myValue: value});
    };




    render() {
        return(
            <form >

                <div>
                    <label>
                        Cursor position looser
                        <br />
                        <input onChange={this.handleCommaSeparatedChange} defaultValue={this.state.myValue} />
                    </label>
                </div>


            </form>
        )
    }
}


  ReactDOM.render(
    <MyFancyForm />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

Comment: Does not work when we are formatting the value by usint 'onChange' event.

Comment: This doesn't work if you change the value in any other way besides typing into the text box. The defaultValue sets the initial value but if you later change that value (besides typing) it doesn't get updated.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by creating a `TextInput` component that wraps `<input type="text">` and proxying the value in internal state.

```js
function TextInput({ value, onChange }) {
    // Create a proxy value in internal state to prevent the caret from jumping to the end every time the value updates
    const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState<string>(value);

    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentValue(value);
    }, [value]);

    return (<input
                type="text"
                value={currentValue}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    setCurrentValue(e.target.value);

                    onChange(e.target.value);
                }}
            />);
}
```

Then I use it in a parent component like so. It works well so far.

```js
<TextInput                  
    value={textValue}
    onChange={(e) => {
        setTextValue(e);
    }}
/>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain why this works!

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old post but this might help someone.

I found this snippet in one github issue and helped me to get around this problem.

```
onChange={(event) => {
  event.persist()
  const caretStart = event.target.selectionStart;
  const caretEnd = event.target.selectionEnd;
  // update the state and reset the caret
  this.updateState();
  event.target.setSelectionRange(caretStart, caretEnd);
}}
```

Quote from:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/955#issuecomment-469344232

Comment: The only problem is that setSelectionRange doesn't work on all input types. For example type=number or email.